# Date Function is trimming seconds where seconds is 00

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, date-conversion, parseexception

```
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-02-02T13:55:00Z");
odtB.toString()
```

prints `2019-02-02T13:55` as output. As because of this my conversion function is throwing error!!

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM\''YY HH:mm aa");
String parsedDate = odtB.format(otdB);
```

How to stop OffsetDateTime or anyOther Java DateTime class from trimming seconds off when seconds are 00??

Comment: What are you really trying to obtain? A string like `02-Feb'19 01:55 PM`? And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java8, you do not need `SimpleDateFormat` any more, it's troublesome.

I suggest to use [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME):

> The ISO date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with an
>   offset, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'.

Example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-02-02T13:55:00Z");
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
        System.out.print(f.format(odtB)); // 2019-02-02T13:55:00Z
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `java.time.LocalDateTime` (which you should since Java 8), you can use different `DateTimeFormatter`s, which you can configure (give them a pattern) to not trimming trailing zeros. See the following example using your date `String` with a slightly adjusted pattern:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-02T13:55:00Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM\''YY HH:mm:ss")));
```

This prints `02-Feb'19 13:55:00`, which hopefully is what you want.

Comment: Why do you suggest to use `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: You are right, it could just be replaced by `OffsetDateTime`, but the `DateTimeFormatter` along with the patterns should stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is from an old and obsolete way of working with Dates. It is also not Thread-safe and has a lot of other problems. In other words don't use it. You need to use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) Please read the javadoc (link provided). It gives detailed explanation how to use it. However the cause of your problem is that in your format mask you are missing placeholder for seconds, thus when your String has seconds it doesn't conform with your format. Change the format to `dd-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss aa` emphases on "ss" - the missing seconds placeholder and it will work